# Rails DRY nested forms for multiple views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, dry

I'm trying to create a DRY form that I could use as form_fields for other, nested forms in different view. I'm having 2 problems.

1. I want the `_form` partial to not have a submit button, and rather have this button on the form itself. However, clicking the submit button in it's current place doesn't do anything??
2. The form displays fine in it's current state. If I move the submit button to the `_form` just to see that it saves, I get a routing error for `uninitialized constant UsersController`?

My code:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users

resources :users do
  resources :projects
end
```

**user.rb model** - I'm using Devise.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :on => :create,
                       :format => {:with => /\A.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\@\#\$\%\^\&\+\=]).*\Z/ }

  has_many :projects, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects

end
```

**projects.rb model**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :projects
  ...
end
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

...

def new
  @project = current_user.projects.build
end

def create
  @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
  if @project.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Your project is being reviewed. We will be in contact soon!'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

...

private

...

def project_params
  params.require(:project)
        .permit(
          :user_id, :project_type_id, :name, :industry_id, 
          :description, :budget_id, :project_status_id, feature_ids:[], addon_ids:[]
        )
end

end
```

**_form.html.erb partial view**

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>      
  <div class="project_form">
    <ol>
      <div class="field entry_box">
        <li><%= f.label "Give your project a name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "A short name", class: "form-control entry_field" %></li>
      </div>

      ...... # All of the other form fields

      <div class="field entry_box">
        <li><%= f.label "What budget do you have in mind?" %>
        <%= collection_select(:project, :budget_id, Budget.all, :id, :list_of_budgets, {include_blank: 'Please select'}, {class: "form-control entry_field"} ) %></li>
      </div>
    </ol>
    # No f.submit button -> moved to view
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**new.html.erb view for new projects**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <h1>New Project</h1>
  </div>

  <%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for @project do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'form', :locals =>  { f: builder } %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions center space_big">
      <%= f.submit "Save Project", class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

1. How do I get the submit button in it's current position to work?
2. What's causing the routing error for `uninitialized constant UsersController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_form` partial you dont need the first line i.e `form_for` since you have already passed `f` which is a `form ('builder')` object for `projects` since you created it inside of `fields_for @project` block.

so this much will do:

```
<div class="project_form">
<ol>
  <div class="field entry_box">
    <li><%= f.label "Give your project a name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "A short name", class: "form-control entry_field" %></li>
  </div>

  ...... # All of the other form fields

  <div class="field entry_box">
    <li><%= f.label "What budget do you have in mind?" %>
    <%= collection_select(:project, :budget_id, Budget.all, :id, :list_of_budgets, {include_blank: 'Please select'}, {class: "form-control entry_field"} ) %></li>
  </div>
</ol>
# No f.submit button -> moved to view
</div>
```

and in your `form_for current_user` change `render` line to like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'form', :locals =>  { f: builder } %>
```

and you are getting that `controller error` since you dont have `UsersController` and you are making the `nested_form` for a `User` that is `current_user` so you should have this code inside `UsersController`'s `new` action and `build` a project for user there.

Comment: Thanks. I've made the change suggested to the `_form` and I get an error for `undefined local variable or method 'f'` referencing `<li><%= f.label "What type of project is this?" %>`?

Comment: Sorry to be clear, that's one of the earlier form fields. It doesn't seem to tie the `f` from the form to the `f` for the fields

Comment: where do you have that label ? because first label I can see is `Give your project a name` so if any error then it should have thrown at that lable since that uses `f` first

Comment: And a possible solution is use `partial` like `render partial: 'form'` . I am updating the answer too with this info

Comment: Awesome thanks, will try that. The label you're seeing is another similar question (I have like 7 questions, but removed all the rest just to make the form simpler for this post). But basically shuffling around the questions it throws the error out for `<li><%= f.label "Give your project a name" %>`

Comment: Sure, try this and let me know any news.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but get the same error `undefined local variable or method 'f'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126223/discussion-between-sajan-and-stephen).